# Terminal cannot find bashrc file when using source command

Tags: bash, terminal

I recently downloaded mysql. What am I doing wrong when I source the bash file?

The path for my bashrc file is:

```
Users/Name/bashrc
```

(I moved it from a different location, can't remember from where, but I figure that if the path is right, it shouldn't matter)

In the terminal, I'm supposed to use:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

When I type that and press enter, it returns:

```
-bash: /Users/Name/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

The bash file itself says:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Comment: `.bashrc` is not the same file as `bashrc`

Comment: Using bashrc returns similar: -bash: /Users/Name/bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: what does `cd ~ && ls -la` return?

Comment: what does `echo $HOME` return?

Comment: echo $HOME returns: /Users/Name

Comment: Wait, are you saying in your last paragraph that your `.bashrc` contains the line `source ~/.bashrc`?  If so, remove that line.

Comment: cd ~ && ls -la returns several lines. bash related stuff includes .bash_history, .bash_profile, .bashrc.save, and bashrc.sh. The last is the file I'm trying to source, and .sh is the extension.

Comment: @ngo There's your problem.  `bashrc.sh` != `.bashrc`.

Comment: So far, I've removed the first two lines from bashrc.sh so that it only has the line export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Comment: When I use "source ~/bashrc.sh", I don't get a no such file or directory error. It might be correct since it shows the mysql version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the file `.bashrc` located in `~` to be able to source it. `~` expands to `$HOME` (`/Users/Name` in your case).

If the output of `cd ~ && ls -la` doesn't contain `.bashrc`, then you don't have that file, so you cannot source it.

Based on your comments, your file is `~/bashrc.sh` (not a great name). If you delete the first two lines of this file, it will work properly. Note that you'll have to `source` this file every time you open a new terminal. You can add the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

to a file that gets automatically sourced upon login, like `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` (not recommended), or create a `~/.bashrc` and include that line.